# SQL - show results from table without values from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

I need to show only results which are in Table1 and Table2 but are not in Table3. Basically, it should be something like TABLE1, Table2 except INNER JOIN between (TABLE1, Table2) and TABLE3.
[Should looks like this - On left side Table1 and Table2, on right side Table3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdpjo.jpg)

Now I have this:

```
SELECT mesta_email, mesta_kod
            FROM Table1
            UNION ALL
            SELECT mesta_email, mesta_kod
            FROM Table2

// And somehow except values which are in Table3
```

Can somebody help me please? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple different ways to do this.  I believe `mysql` does better with the `outer join/null` approach:

```
select t.*
from (
      SELECT mesta_email, mesta_kod
      FROM Table1
      UNION ALL
      SELECT mesta_email, mesta_kod
      FROM Table2
) t left join Table3 t3 on t.mesta_email = t3.mesta_email
                       and t.mesta_kod = t3.mesta_kod
where t3.mesta_email is null
```

This assume `table3` shares the same structure as the other 2 tables.

Comment: And is there a way how to delete duplicates based for ex. on mesta_email? Because now there is shown several results with same email adress.

Comment: @user3142314 -- perhaps you want `union` instead of `union all`?

Comment: But can I define that I want delete duplicated based on for ex. mesta_email? If in tables will be mesta_kod differnet but mesta_email same, than it shoud show only one row with only one mesta_email.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach the problem almost directly as you write it, using `exists` and `not exists`:

```
select t1.mesta_email, t2.mesta_kod
from table1 t1
where exists (select 1
              from table2 t2
              where t2.mesta_email = t1.mesta_email and t2.mesta_kod = t1.mesta_kod 
             ) and
       not exists (select 1
                   from table3 t3
                   where t3.mesta_email = t1.mesta_email and t3.mesta_kod = t1.mesta_kod 
                  );
```

One advantage of `exists`/`not exists` over other approaches involves duplicates.  If one of the tables (say `table1`) has not duplicates, but the others might, there is no need to remove duplicates in the resulting data set.